# Point to files inside the apk?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using phonegap to develop an android application. In my javaclass I want to point to a file in the "assets/www/" directory, what would be the full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the path, use `getAssets().open(assetPath);`

An example may be:

```
private static final int READ_EULA_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
private static final String FILE_PATH = "www/yourfile";

BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(FILE_PATH), BUFFER_SIZE);

String line;
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(line).append('\n');
}
return buffer;
```

Comment: path may be incorrect, I have only used it to access file directly under /assets (and call "filename"). I assume www/filename will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

All the paths are relative to your project home directory. The project home directory is the root (/) and all the other paths are relative to this. This is not just the case with android but for all the java projects(as a matter of fact in most of the other languages too).